# Swift recursive struct in db cannot solved Codable compliant

Tags: swift, codable, jsondecoder

Swift recursive struct can be solved by helper struct as given below. Unfortunately, this is not Codable compliant:

```
class Box<T> {
   let boxed: T
   init(_ thingToBox: T) { boxed = thingToBox }
}

struct ContainerClass: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: UUID?
    var classname: String
    var parent: Box<ContainerClass>?

    private enum ContainerClassKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case classname
        case parent
    }
}
```

> Error: Type 'ContainerClass' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

Comment: `class Box<T: Codable>: Codable {...}`, this makes the error go away

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works to the extent that I can compile without errors. But then I get the errorDecodingData:   guard let objects = try? JSONDecoder().decode([T].self, from: data) 
<T> ContainerClass

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing more about the context.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: thank you very much, just read it. Will reply tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

You must make `Box` conform to `Codable`.

You can use conditional conformance to only make `Box` `Codable` when its generic type `T` is `Codable` as well.

```
final class Box<T> {
    let boxed: T
    init(_ thingToBox: T) { boxed = thingToBox }
}

struct ContainerClass: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: UUID?
    var classname: String
    var parent: Box<ContainerClass>?

    private enum ContainerClassKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case classname
        case parent
    }
}

extension Box: Codable where T: Codable {
    convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let boxed = try container.decode(T.self)
        self.init(boxed)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(boxed)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you always want `T` to be `Codable`, you can simplify the code to

```
class Box<T: Codable>: Codable {
    let boxed: T
    init(_ thingToBox: T) { boxed = thingToBox }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, just read it. Will reply tomorrow